# How to moderate facebook comment

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-comments

i am trying to moderate facebook's plugin of comments. But his documentation about this is not clear for me. I tried to integrate but it is not working.

Anyone knows how to implement this?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s);
       js.id = id;
       js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId=301163393374987';
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://teste/comments/"
 data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

**Notes**:

- This code is just a example, the `appId` and the link belongs to facebook.
- I configured on developers.facebook.com the restriction about comments.(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/YOURAPPID/)
- Note: I tried to set `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APP_ID}"/>`  on code too, but it makes no effect.
- Official Documentation about facebook's comment: (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#)

Any response will be appreciate.

Comment: what does it mean to moderate a facebook comment? What to you mean when you ask how to implement this? This question seems very unclear to me. The link you provided is also no help.

Comment: Take in mind the link bellow is the official documentation of facebook.
This is the page that explain what is moderation: (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator). It means that i want to analyse all comments when people comment. The comments could be offensive, understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your meta tag inside the header.

Something like this:

```
<meta property='fb:app_id' content='xxxxxxxxxx' />
```

Where the content is your app id on facebook app. Probably that's what you need to get it working, other side it doesn't work at all.

Also, make sure you have these other ones:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="URL" />
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE" />
<meta property="og:description" content="DESC" />
<meta property="og:image" content="IMG" />
```

To check if it's working you can use the fb debug tool at:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?

Just add your URL to check if it's ok.